# 連続する２つの数字の片方を置換して消したい

Tags: 正規表現

notepadエディタで以下のようなことがしたいです。

```
00001297    00001297
00001235    00001235
00001245    00001245
```

上記のような数字を

```
00001297
00001235
00001245
```

のように片方だけにしたいです。
どのような置換方法がありますでしょうか？

Comment: 繰り返しますが、質問する際は環境に関する情報を正確に記述してください。「正規表現」というタグが最初から付いているので、Windows標準のメモ帳 (notepad) ではなく、正規表現が使える「notepad++」か何かの間違いかと思って正規表現を回答しましたが、本当にWindows標準のメモ帳を使っているのであれば正規表現は使えません。正規表現に対応した別のエディターと、提示した正規表現を使って実現できるのであれば、マイナス評価は取り消していただきたいです。

Comment: @sygh 投票は常に匿名なので、基本的に誰がマイナスを入れたのかは分かりません (今回も質問者本人があなたの回答にマイナスしたとは限らない)。 / 質問内容に曖昧だと感じる部分がある場合には、仮定で回答してしまうよりもまずコメントで明確化を求めるか、必要なら質問にクローズ票を入れることも検討してください。

Comment: @sygh denden氏は信用度が 105 なのでそもそも downvote ができません。

Answer (score 0):

質問するときは環境に関する情報を詳しく正確に記述しましょう。

- [技術系メーリングリストで質問するときのパターン・ランゲージ](https://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html#env)

正規表現のエンジンによって回答が変わる可能性があります。
**Windows標準のメモ帳 (notepad.exe) は正規表現に対応していませんが、質問には「正規表現」というタグが最初から付いているので、正規表現に対応した別のエディターを使っているものと仮定します。また、ひとまず一般的なECMA正規表現エンジンだと仮定します。**

キャプチャと部分文字列を使えば実現できると思います。

置換前: `^([0-9]+)\s+\1$`
置換後: `\1`

Answer (score 0):

> notepadエディタで以下のようなことがしたいです。

メモ帳（notepadエディタ）には正規表現は搭載されていません。他のツールを使用してください。

Answer (score 0):

[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) であれば検索や置換処理に正規表現(PCRE)を使用することができますが、この場合は PowerShell を使って処理することも可能です。

**PowerShell script**

```
Get-Content .\data.txt |
ForEach-Object {
  $arr = $_ -split "\s+"
  If ($arr[0] -eq $arr[1]) {$arr[0]} Else {$_}
} | Out-File .\data_uniq.txt
```

**data.txt**

```
00001297    00001297
00001235    00001235
00001245    00001245
00002000    00002001
```

**data_uniq.txt**

```
00001297
00001235
00001245
00002000    00002001
```